# Check if date in table1 is >= than date in table2. If yes, return 'Sent' in new created column called Status

Tags: sql, sas

New guy here. I need to compare a date from one table to the other. The columns on the two tables are identical. I need to find out if a date in one table is greater or equal to the date on another table. Pretty much the below explains what I am wanting to do. I wrote a subquery to ensure the ID is there, but I can't think of a way to check the date.

```
Proc sql;
Create table test as 
Select  *,

    case when ID in (Select ID from Test2) then 'Sent' as Status 

from Test1
WHERE test2.Date(Date from table2) >= test1.date(date from table1);
quit;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `exists`:

```
select t1.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from test2 t2
                          where t2.ID = t1.ID and t2.date >= t1.date
                         )
             then 'Sent'
        end) as Status 
from Test1 t1;
```